# Unable to convert uint8_t array to unsigned long in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino

I am trying to convert **`uint8_t readData[10] = "123456789" ;`** to **`unsigned long`** to do some math on  this value, in Arduino. I'm using **strtoul** function. **strtoul** works fine if I define above array by my self and it converts this array to `unsigned long` successfully. **But** if I put some values in this array by reading **DS1307 NVRAM**, then **`strtoul`** **fails to convert the array into unsigned long and gives 0** answer. I checked values in readData array, after reading NVRAM, using for loop, and found that values are same that i have saved in the NVRAM.
I am using NodeMCU board along with DS1307. My *code* and its *Output* is given below.

```
// Example of using the non-volatile RAM storage on the DS1307.
// You can write up to 56 bytes from address 0 to 55.
// Data will be persisted as long as the DS1307 has battery power.

#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;


 uint8_t readData[9] = "0";    //**this will store integer values from DS1307 NVRAM.
 unsigned long convertedL1 = 0; //this will store converted value
 
 uint8_t savedData[10] = "123456789"; //I have already filled this array for testing strtoul function.
 unsigned long convertedL2 = 0;     //this will store converted value of savedData array

void setup () {
  
Serial.begin(9600);

delay(3000);

#ifndef ESP8266
while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
#endif

  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    delay(3000);
    while(1);
  }

rtc.readnvram(readData,9,2); //Read NVRAM from address 2 to 11.

delay(20);

Serial.println("Prinitng values( using loop) stored in readData array, after reading NVRAM :");
  
  for (int i = 0; i <9; i++) {
     Serial.print(readData[i]);
  }

 Serial.println();

//Converting both arrays of same type using stroul

  convertedL1 = (unsigned long)strtoul((char *)&readData[0],NULL,10);

  convertedL2 = (unsigned long)strtoul((char *)&savedData[0],NULL,10);

  Serial.print("converted value of readData array = ");
  Serial.println(convertedL1);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("converted value of savedData array = ");
  Serial.println(convertedL2);

}//setup end

 

void loop () {
  // Do nothing in the loop.
}
```

**the Output on Serial Monitor is:**

```
Prinitng values( using loop) stored in readData array, after reading NVRAM :
123456789
converted value of readData array = 0

converted value of savedData array = 123456789
```

Why **strtoul** function works with one array and not with other.I searched many forums but couldn't find any solution.
Can anyone, please have a look at my code and kindly suggest me the solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `strtoul` expects a string.  Does `readData` have number `char`s and is it `NUL` terminated?

Comment: `readData` has only numbers inside it but it was not being `NUL` terminated after being accessed by `rtc.readnvram` function. I added `'\0'` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Seems likely the reason for the difference is that your `savedData` array is null terminated but your `readData` array is not. `strtoul` requires that the array be null terminated.

Change your code like this

```
uint8_t readData[10] = "0"; // one extra byte for null terminator

...

rtc.readnvram(readData,9,2); //Read NVRAM from address 2 to 11.
readData[9] = '\0';          // add the null terminator
```

Comment: The declaration of `readData` fills it with nulls, doesn't it?

Comment: Two strings walk into a bar. One says "A beer, please!$6(////^%"%2$@". The other says, "You'll have to excuse my friend, he's not null terminated." Just a little aide-memoir.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, but if every one of those nulls then gets replaced by a non-null, the string is no longer null-terminated.

Comment: @TonyK That's true because readData is global, but in the original code there was only nine bytes, so no room for the null terminator. And in any case if the null terminator is vital it makes sense to ensure it's there at the point where you need it, rather than relying on a declaration in some other part of the code.

Comment: Yes John, you were right. Your solution worked for me. `readData` was not `NUL` terminated. Now it is working fine. I appreciate all commenters' for your discussion on my question.